# Set Timer from another class to fire in another view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nstimer

EDIT: Added the NSRunLoop from my code, as mentioned by Deepak below.  This was originally in my code and forgot to add as it was commented out.

I have 2 classes:  MainViewController, and ConfigViewController.  The user switches to the ConfigView and uses a UIDatePicker / UIButton combo to set a Date/Time.  Upon grabbing the correct time from the UIDatePicker object, I setup a NSTimer to fire as per the following code:

**ConfigViewController.m**

```
-(IBAction)setAlarmDate:(id)sender {
//Instantiate to get access to doAlarm:
MainViewController *mvc = [[MainViewController alloc] init];

dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormat setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSString *target = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];

alarmDate = [datePicker date];

mvc.fireTimer = [[NSTimer alloc] 
                  initWithFireDate:alarmDate interval:1 target:mvc
                  selector:@selector(doAlarm:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
[runLoop addTimer:mvc.timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];


[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

The doAlarm: method is as follows:

**MainViewController.m**

```
- (void)doAlarm:(NSTimer *)timer {

NSLog(@"Called doAlarm:");

UIImage *ac = [UIImage imageNamed:@"alarmclock.png"];
[self.alarmview setImage:ac];
[self.alarmview setHidden:NO];
[self.view addSubview:alarmview];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:alarmview];

}
```

However, when I set the alarm date, the timer fails to fire.  I think the following problems are afoot:

1) I am instantiating a new instance of the MainViewController class, setting the Timer going and then passing control back to the "original" instance of MainViewController when I dismiss the MVC.  At this point, probably the "new" instance of MainViewController is nothing but a dangling pointer, and is never referenced again anyway, hence no segfault.

2) doAlarm: references self.view, which is *supposed* to be the MainViewController.view, but as it's instantiated in the scope of ConfigViewController, the alarm image would never be seen anyway...

I imagine my theories are a bit unfounded, but with my current level of knowledge, they make sense to me.

Any light you can shed on the above would be smashing.

Many thanks!

swisscheese.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to the documentation for [`initWithFireDate:interval:target:selector:userinfo:repeats:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/initWithFireDate%3ainterval%3atarget%3aselector%3auserInfo%3arepeats%3a), you will notice that while the timer is initialized it is not scheduled yet. You will need to add it a  `NSRunLoop` to make it work. Do this after you have initialized an alarm as above.

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

You can also consider using the `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` which does that for you.

There are of course few other things here.

**New MainViewController object**

You guessed it right. You are creating an unrelated object which will just leak. To solve this you can maintain a weak reference to the `MainViewController` object. You can do this as follows -

```
@class MainViewController; // Forward declaration 

@interface ConfigViewController {
    ...
    MainViewController *mainViewController;
}
...
@property (nonatomic, assign) MainViewController *mainViewController;
...
@end
```

in `ConfigViewController.m`:

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

@implementation ConfigViewController

@synthesize mainViewController;
...

- (IBAction)setAlarmDate:(id)sender {
    dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateFormat setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

    alarmDate = [datePicker date];

    mainViewController.fireTimer = [[NSTimer alloc] 
                  initWithFireDate:alarmDate interval:1 target:mainViewController
                  selector:@selector(doAlarm:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [runLoop addTimer:mainViewController.timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    mainViewController = nil;
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
...
@end
```

**Timer**

I am not sure if you need a repeating timer here. There is an alternative - `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`. This will invoke a method on an object this is called after the desired delay. Does what it calls itself. It will be something like this -

```
[mvcReference performSelector:@selector(doAlarm) 
                   withObject:nil 
                   afterDelay:[datePicker.date timeIntervalSinceNow]];
```

**doAlarm:**

I did not get what you wanted to know here but you are right. `self` is a reference to the `MainViewController` object. Unless you retained the view controller that you displayed modally, it would have been dismissed and deallocated by then.

Comment: Thanks Deepak - I did indeed note that initWithFireDate needs the timer to be added to a RunLoop.  I have edited my code accordingly.  By weak reference, should I instantiate a "global" instance of MainViewController (like a duplicate one, of which will be used), @property it _weak, and then replace all references to self with the new instance?  I am sure I am overlooking some fundamental tenet of OOP here, as I seem to be hitting a limitation of my knowledge with cross-class messaging.  Perhaps I should have a new class with the alarm method only, and see if I get anywhere there.Thanks again!

Comment: I have added what I meant regarding the `MainViewController` in the answer in the appropriate section.

Comment: Thanks Deepak - still not having any luck, it just silently refuses to execute the method.  I am trying to proxy the call inside a local method, and I can confirm that I am able to call the proxy method with the Timer/RunLoop setup.  From that proxy method, along with a NSLog to log that i'm in the method, I also try [mvcReference doAlarm] but unfortunately nothing happens - I will keep digging, but I think I might have to redesign my entire app based on this problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No but did you set it `mainViewCOntroller` before presenting the modal view controller? `configViewController.mainViewController = self;` and `[self presentModalViewController:configViewController animated:YES];`

Comment: Hi Deepak, thank you for the suggestion.  I implemented it, but still no luck calling doAlarm: i'm afraid.  It just seems like this function is not reached.  I think I need to read up on how best to design MVC apps, as I believe my design is wrong.  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: In closing, I think I will be looking into using a singleton class to store the alarmDate, and/or delegates to set the date.  I'm reading through the infamous Design Patterns book to get a clue, as reading back through my code, it's clear that my design is flawed and would've become unmanageable as the program grew (not that an alarm clock would grow much but you never know).  Marking answer as thanks to Deepak.